# What am I doing wrong when splitting lines from a textfile

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a quiz for my computer science program and the idea is having keywords and definitions. The User will be shown a keyword that gets randomized and three definitions in radiobuttons, one must be the correct answer.

I decided to put my keywords and my defintions in the same file like so:

```
Keyword1 = Definition1
Keyword2 = Definition2
Keyword3 = Definition3
```

etc.

On my main form I have the following loop:

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("my-file-path-here")
Dim Pair() As String = line.split("=")
LabelKeyword.text = Trim(Pair(0)) ' Needs Randomizing
RadioButtonDef1.text = Trim(Pair(1)) ' Needs randomizing
'RadioButtonDef2.text = 'Don't know needs randomizing
'RadioButtonDef3.text = 'Don't know needs randomizing
Next
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to randomize the keywords and the definitions. Also I have 15 lines in my text file and it always seems to only read the last line.

So my questions are:

1. How can I randomize the keywords and the definitions always having one of the definitions the answer to the current keyword.
2. Why does it only read the very last line of my text file and how can I fix it?
3. I also need to be able to make the quiz only finish when every keyword has been matched to its definition twice. Their time taken also needs to be recored as they play.

Comment: that not your complete code (no `Next`), but you are assigning each keyword/def to the **same** label and radio pair so only the last pair remain when you are done.  For the rest, dont try to do everything in the loop.  Read the file into something like a List, then pick random one for display.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. I added the next my mistake. I am learning visual basic. I had a different way before but a member on DaniWeb recommended I use this method however I don't know how to randomize the Keywords and definitions when it only reads the last line of the file...

Comment: its not reading just the last line - its reading them all, you can only see the last one because line 1 is overwritten by line 2, that by line 3 etc.  set a breakpoint and compare what happens to what you think should happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through all of the lines in your text file, but you are displaying all of them in the same control.  Therefore, each time you iterate through the loop, it overwrites the values in the controls from the last iteration.  I would strongly suggest storing your values in some sort of data-structure in memory.  Then you can access the values randomly at will.  For instance, you could store all the values in a `Dictionary`, like this:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("...")
    Dim pair() As String = line.Split("=")
    dict(pair(0)) = pair(1)
Next
```

Comment: So would I then randomize the dictionary outside the loop?

Comment: Yes.  After you are done loading the data into memory, then you could read from it in any random order or you could re-order the list randomly.  If you need to change the order of the list, I would recommend using a `List` rather than a `Dictionary`.  For instance, you could use a `List(Of KeyValuePair)`.

Comment: So for the list would I change where I Dim the Dictionary to something like: `Dim myList As List(Of String)`? If so how would I list the Keywords and Definitions?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to change the line where you declare it and you'd also have to change where you add the items.  You'd need to create a `KeyValuePair` object (or whatever other type of object you choose to use in your list) and then call `myList.Add` to add that new pair object to the list.  As far as how to read the data out of the list, I'm sure you want to take a stab at figuring it out for yourself first.  I'd hate to write it all for you and deprive you of the learning experience :)  If you get stuck, though, feel free to ask a new question.  We're always willing to help!